# How to Change an FA to a Push Down Automata

Tags: finite-automata

I am supposed to draw a Push Down Automata that would function the way a normal calculator would which accepts only correct mathematic expressions. I was given an FA but i dont know how to change it to a PDA, so please give me a crash course on PDA and help me out on the problem.[Finite Automata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9aSr.jpg)

Please give me the easiest possible explanation of how a PDA works like im a 5 year old. (i've tried alot and couldnt figure out)